# Include Cocos2d Particle System in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I started writing my game in vanilla OpenGL ES 2.0. Now I'm thinking about adding some sort of particle system for a nice effect.

Is there a way to include a particle system that can easily be created in Cocos2d to my OpenGL app? That would save me all the trouble (and is probably more performant) of creating a particle system on my own.

If not, are there maybe other frameworks that I can use to create a simple particle system in OpenGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d includes a particle system for its own framework. When you leave the framework and start writing in OpenGL (the language used as the backend of Cocos2d) you are losing the framework. You'll have to write your own particle system.

This is a great tutorial for the basics.
http://www.71squared.com/en/article/806/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-8-particle-emitter

The same company also makes a great app to make particle creation easy. It also includes some steps to get started using it in your projects that don't use Cocos2d.
http://www.71squared.com/en/particledesigner